# What should be written in MIT license (year, full name)?

Tags: licensing, mit

I am creating an open source project and I want to use an MIT license for that. I have found this page: http://choosealicense.com/licenses/mit/

What should I write under "full name"? Should the group of people, that I am working with be registered as a company? If I am the head developer, and other people are freelancers that I have hired, can I (or should I) just write my own name instead of the company's name?

Under the "year" should I write basically the current year, the years when this project is available as open source or the year this product was released?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All these details are part of the copyright statement, i.e.

> ```
> Copyright (c) [year] [fullname]
> ```

As such, they should be filled in with the details of the copyright that applies to the licensed work.

`[year]` is the **year copyright was applied**. If you apply the copyright (which happens automatically when you write the work) in 2015, put in 2015. Some people like to put in a range of years (i.e. 2015-2020) - this isn't necessary.

`[fullname]` is the **full name of the entity that owns the copyright**. If the owning entity is a private individual, put their name in:

```
Copyright (c) 2015, jackson
```

If it's a company (and although you may write the code, if you write it for a company, your employment contract probably contains a copyright assignment clause), put in the name of the company:

```
Copyright (c) 2015, Stack Exchange, Inc.
```

Additionally, if you're using [choosealicense](http://choosealicense.com), each license page has a section called **How to apply this license**. You can find it on the top of the right-hand column of the page.

Comment: If I want to put my own name, should I register it somewhere (that this project belongs to me)? Because anyone can call themselves the name I will provide. And what if I will write the nick name? Is it going to be wrong?  Why?

Comment: @jackson Never put a nickname on a project's copyright statement; I've only done that above for illustration. Use your real name. You don't need to register ownership anywhere.

Comment: What happens If I will put a nickname? Jail?

Comment: @jackson No, but your copyright becomes unenforceable because it can't be proven whose the nickname is.

Comment: But I am sure that there are people that have the same name and surname as I do. What if they will try to "steal" this project?

Comment: Consider: every book ever published has someone's ordinary name on the copyright page. Software lives in the same legal universe.

Comment: @jackson Simply put, they won't. The chances of that happening are so impossibly small that they may as well not exist. If it does, I'm sure there's some legal mechanism of proving your ownership.

Comment: Well, thank you a lot! You have really helped me! That is all I needed to know.

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped.

Comment: @bmargulies That's incorrect. Many books are published under a pen name. That does not mean that the copyright can not be enforced.

Comment: OK, OK, 'almost every'. I was trying to make the opposite point; that authors don't run around picking silly names to make it _easier_ to enforce.

Comment: I don't think anyone mentioned if you have multiple people, like you alluded to in your question: you can list as many copyright notices as you need for each person who owns a portion of copyright in the program.

Comment: To avoid updating the year every year, can it be left out? Would version control history be sufficient to see what year the copyright went into effect?

Comment: @Dennis Probably, but I wouldn't chance legal hassle for the cost of a minute each year. I tend to use `Copyright (c) 2018- ArtOfCode` (i.e. unterminated range) in copyright statements.